# Passing frame captured image to other function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

```
        cropIrisImage = imcrop(iResize, [c(1)-120, ro(1)-100, 225, 220]);
        figure,imshow(cropIrisImage);title('Cropped Iris Image');
        [r,c,d] = size(cropIrisImage);              %# Get the image size
        set(gca,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1]);  %# Modify axes size
        set(gcf,'Units','pixels','Position',[200 200 c r]);  %# Modify figure size
        hold on;

        f = getframe(gcf);
        img_cropIris = image(f.cdata);
        figure,imshow(img_cropIris);title('Croped Iris Image');
```

I have try to get image from showing axes by
                      getframe(gcf)
and get it but yet not be able to store it in the image. I have also written it on disk using 
    imwrite
 later but i need to store it in the function (in some variable of uint8) so as well after image(f.cdata) so i can pass it to other function which perform some operations like rgb2gray and at all. Thanks...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Can't you just save `f.cdata` in a new variable and share it with other functions by passing it as an input argument?

Comment: Thank You very much :)...it works for me. I was trying 'image(f.cdata)' to store in a new variable your answer bring me up to exact what i want. Thanks again

Comment: Awesome then glad I could help!